# calling swift file in seperate project from objective c project. Apple Mach-o Linker error

Tags: objective-c, swift, linker-errors, objective-c-swift-bridge

we have a legacy iOS objective C app. We want to add "swift" functionality. Created a separate "Cocoa touch framework" project to reference it from the "objective C" project. I am getting this error when I try to call/init any of the methods in swift from objective c

> Ld /Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/super.app/super normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/teeboy/iWorkbench/super
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk -L/Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/teeboy/iWorkbench/super -filelist /Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Intermediates/super.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/super.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/super.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Intermediates/super.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/super.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/super_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -all_load -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Intermediates/super.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/super.build/super.app.xcent -lz -lPatientSearch -framework MapKit -framework ZipArchive -framework QuartzCore -lMobuleMenuCell -framework OCMockitoIOS -framework Security -lModuleNavigation -lToDoList -framework CoreData -lPatientChart -framework CoreText -framework Crashlytics -framework CoreLocation -lVisitNotes -lDataAccess -lDashboard -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -lframework -lsuperCommon -framework UIKit -framework OCHamcrestIOS -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Intermediates/super.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/super.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/super_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/teeboy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/super-aybvkjtipygrszeyqsnbmtglaaqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/super.app/super
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC5utils3zip", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libDashboard.a(ASLandingPageVC.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The name of swift library is "utils". The legacy objective c app uses some other project dependencies. sorry, newbie to xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how you referenced the Swift framework in the Objective-C app, I can only guess that you referenced a framework binary that is built for a platform different from the one you are trying to build the app for.

For instance, this would happen if you built the framework for a device, then included, in the Framework Search Paths under the app's Build Settings, the path to the directory containing the resulting .framework directory and then tried to build the app for a simulator.  It would work if you used the correct framework binary (built for the simulator in this case).

However, a more elegant way of doing this is to embed the Swift framework in your application.  Assuming the framework and the app are in different projects, you might do the following:

- Ensure that the framework project is not open in Xcode.
- Open the app project in Xcode.
- Drag the framework's .xcodeproj from Finder to the app project in Xcode to create a reference.
- Under General -> Embedded Binaries add your Swift .framework.
- When you build the app, Xcode will build the framework for the correct architecture and use and embed it in your app.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html for more info about embedding frameworks.  BTW, when the linker failed, did you also see a warning from `ld` about a file missing a required architecture?

Comment: Excellent omniProg. Your steps solved the issue. Removed the "swift framework" project from workspace. Dragged and dropped it from finder onto xcode "App" project and it works now. The only additional step I had to do was set "Always embed swift standard libraries" to "yes" in "general' tab on app's project properties. After working for more than 12 years on Visual Studio, xCode is surely a different beast! atleast we have swift which is closer to c# than objective c ever will be..